# why the main app doesn't exit when calling a timer.schedule

Tags: scala, schedule

In the following,it run a calcuation after delay 2 seconds, but when run the app, it never exit. What is the code blocking the app to exit?

```
object Test extends App{
   import scala.concurrent._
   import java.util._
   import java.util.concurrent.{ TimeUnit }
   val timer = new java.util.Timer()
   def timeoutFuture[A](v: A, delay: Long, unit: TimeUnit): Future[A] = {
    println("inner")
    val p = Promise[A]()
    println("inner")
    timer.schedule(new java.util.TimerTask {
      def run() {
        p.success(v)
      }
    }, unit.toMillis(delay))
    println("inner")
    p.future
   }
   println("begin")
   val x1=timeoutFuture[Int](1+1,2,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
   println("end")
   println("quit")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val timer = new java.util.Timer()` will start a `TimerThread` (which extends a standard Java thread and is implemented as an infinite loop), which is running in the background and prevent your application from exiting.

You can run `System.exit(0)` at the end of your script to stop all the background threads.

Also have you considered using [Akka scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/scheduler.html) instead of Java Timer?

Comment: the def of timeoutFuture is copied from playframework, so maybe we could use Akka scheduler to replace it?it's from framework/src/iteratees/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Concurrent.scala